Custom `derive` macro without the actual `Trait` to be derived
Currently, implementing a custom derive macro does not require an actual Trait to exist at all. All it does is to append an arbitrary code block after the annotated item, and apparently to remove the "helper attributes" from it. That is we can do something like the following:
#[proc_macro_derive(FakeTrait)]

pub fn custom_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let name = ... // Get the ident name from input
    ....
        quote! {
        impl #name {
            fn custom_function(...) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }.into()   
}

And then we can use this macro on a struct via
#[derive(FakeTrait)]
struct MyStruct {...}

and it will happily work by appending the impl MyStruct to it regardless the existence of FakeTrait.
My question is whether it is an acceptable use-case for derive macros? Are there any downsides and could it happen that it breaks in the future?

To the "opinion based" close-voter. The fact you believe it is opinion based implies that it is an acceptable use-case. Otherwise there would be a clear guideline that it is not. In either case it is not opinion based.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-macros

@cafce25 I read this reference in every direction dozens of times :) Are you saying that the given example implies that this is a valid usage not to have a trait to be derived?

@EugeneSh. That's not what opinion-based means.

This question is asking three separate questions. The first question, whether it's acceptable, is opinion-based. The second question is actually two questions, the first of which is currently unqualified and thus unanswerable (what do you consider a downside?) without delving into further opinions, and the second of which is purely speculative (how could we know whether something may break in the future?), AKA opinion-based. This question is thus in need of focus because all three of its questions are opinion-based.

The question could be salvaged if you can revise it so that it asks one practical, objective question (that does not invalidate the existing answer by kmdreko).

@TylerH The practical question is would be even more "opinion based" - it is "When I need to implement a macro to append some code to the macro input, should I resort to using the custom derive macro, or to more complicated proc_macro"? The answer below is fully addressing this question quite factually if you ask me, without involving any opinions.

It is certainly the most common case that derive macros generate an implementation for a trait with the same name, but that is not enforced. So likely as long as its clear what your macro is doing it'd probably be "acceptable".
For prior art: the enum_as_inner crate exposes the EnumAsInner derive macro that does not generate any trait implementations and instead generates inherent methods.

Good find. I take it that it is an ok practice as the big kids are already using it this way.
